# error while using pkcs12 certificate with tomcat 9

Tags: ssl, tomcat, pkcs#12

I am using below command to run tomcat 9 docker image,

```
docker run \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/keystore.p12 \
  -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=pskp \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=PKCS12 \
  -e TOMCAT_SSL_PORT=8443 \
  -e KEY_PASSWORD=pskp \
  -e TOMCAT_SSL_CIPHERS="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_12
8_GCM_SHA256" \
  -v /home/parikshit/certs/server.p12:/usr/local/tomcat/keystore.p12 \
tomcat:9
```

It is starting without any error. but when I try to curl, getting error.

```
$ curl https://localhost:8443
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

chatgpt asked me to run below command,

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the pkcs12 certificate correctly like below

```bash
# this command will ask info & password
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myKey.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in cert.pem
```

After this command, you will have 3 files. We care about `keyStore.p12`.

### Catalina settings

Adding whole file `server.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
      Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
        UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443"
              maxParameterCount="1000"
              />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxParameterCount="1000"
              keystoreFile="${keystore.file}"
              keystorePass="${keystore.pass}"
              keystoreType="PKCS12" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
              >
    </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
              resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
              prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
              pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

In the above file, we have 2 variables `keystore.file` (location of p12 file) and `keystore.pass` (you set while creating certs).

### Using docker

I believe `keyStore.p12` and `server.xml` are in the same folder on your machine. Go to that folder and run the below command. If your server is not starting on 8443 and starting on 8080, check `CATALINA_HOME`. In my case, it is `/usr/local/tomcat`

```bash
docker run \
  -p 8081:8443 \
  -e CATALINA_OPTS="-Dkeystore.pass=<password_here> -Dkeystore.file=/certs/keystore.p12" \
  -v .\keyStore.p12:/certs/keystore.p12 \
  -v .\server.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml \
  tomcat:9
```